# Send attachments through email

Tags: sandbox

I have one custom object suppose naming Invoice. When I create a record and attach three or more attachments, at that time an email should be send with those many attachments. those attachments can be different every time i.e want dyanamic.

Is there any way to implement this flow?

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a Trigger on Custom object
2. In trigger check that the record has attachment or not.
3. If record has attachment associated
4. Create an email programmatically in trigger as:

   // fetch attachments for Opportunity
          List attList = [SELECT id, Name, body, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = : opp.id];

   ```
      // List of attachments handler
      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] efaList = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
      for(Attachment att : attList)
      {
        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName(att.Name);
        efa.setBody(att.body);
        efa.setContentType(att.ContentType);
        efa.setInline(false);
        efaList.add(efa);
      }

       // Attach files to email instance
       email.setFileAttachments(efaList);
   ```

I answered similar question perviously here [Send an email with files attached with a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/send-an-email-with-files-attached-with-a-trigger)